# MySQL won't start - only 480 error messages, but it should contain at least 481 error messages

Tags: mysql, startup

I updated mysql and not it won't start. I tried removing it and reinstalling and it still will not start. I get the following error in the logs. When you start it it just tells you that mysql timed out. I get more information by looking at the error log:

Error message file '/usr/share/mysql/english/errmsg.sys' had only 480 error messages,
but it should contain at least 481 error messages.
Check that the above file is the right version for this program!

Answer (score 1):

You can verify the package using:

rpm -V mysql-server

debsums -c mysql-server

This will show if that file is not what the package manager expects.  The package may be called MySQL-server or just MySQL as well, depending on the source of the package (community version uses caps, redhat/debian distribs use all-lowercase).

I would check here, to make sure the packages are indeed what the system expects.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'd be doing what the error message says, and verifying (from upstream sources) that `errmsg.sys` is for the correct version of MySQL.  Sounds like you've got a dodgy package that doesn't have all the right files in it.

Answer (score 0):

You might try adding a bogus line to the end of errmsg.sys so that it *thinks* there are 481 messages.  That *might* be enough to allow MySQL to start.

If this works, I would still grab the correct errmsg.sys file from the source tarball.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the my.cnf file is a bit messed up.  In your currently loading my.cnf file, if there is a line saying something like:

```
language = /some/thing/english
```

Comment it out and try starting it again.  It's possible your re-installed mysql into a different location, and the old error file is being referenced instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you have another instance version, you can copy and paste the `errmsg.sys`, like this:

1 - Rename the wrong `errmsg.sys`, mine is `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\share\english\errmsg.sys` to `errmsg.sys1`

2 - I have another instance 5.7 that I copied from `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\share\english\errmsg.sys` to `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\share\english\errmsg.sys`.

3- Start the service..

I believe if you have 5.1 and 5.6 can run too..